# What HTTP error should I return if an external API called by my API is down

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi

A client calls my RESTful API, which internally calls another API for some data. This other API can be both internal or external to our organization. What HTTP error should my API return if the dependent API is down? Will the answer be the same if this other API returns AUTH error?

Answer (score 1):

It will be certainly `5xx` error, because it is server related. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#server_error_responses

I would use `503 Service Unavailable`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503